# Weblogic server level workmanager not being used

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g, workmanagers

I have defined a work manager (Global Workmanager) which has targets as managed servers.

When an ear application (containing many ejbs) is deployed on the server and the ejbs are invoked, it only uses the default WorkManager the server level workmanager is not being used. Even a server level MaxThreadsConstraint is also not being respected.

I don't want to edit deployment descriptors to be flexible in configuration.

Is there anything else to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use the weblogic deployments descriptors, I guess you'll have to [override the default Work Manager](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/config_wls/self_tuned.html#wp1066991):

> You can override the behavior of the default Work Manager by creating and configuring a global Work Manager called `default`. This allows you to control the default thread-handling behavior of WebLogic Server.

Comment: Thanks, this worked out. I still wonder though, why the custom workmanager is ignored.